# Convert org-time-stamp

Tags: org-mode, time-date

I need a function that can determine whether an org-time-stamp in a table equals the current date.

**Example:**

```
#+NAME: test
| date             | breakfast |
|------------------+-----------|
| <2015-11-06 Fri> | eggs      |
| <2015-11-07 Sat> | oatmel    |
```

I can get the timestamp from last line in above table with `org-table-get-remote-range`. For example:

```
(substring-no-properties (org-table-get-remote-range "test" "@<$1"))
```

Returns:

```
<2015-11-07 Sat>
```

How can I convert that string to a number so that I can compare it with something like:

```
(format-time-string "%Y%m%d" (current-time))?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `org-read-date` to convert timestamp strings into internal times

```
(org-read-date nil t "<2015-11-06>" nil)
```

This can be compared to either `(org-read-date nil t "today" nil)` which always returns the current date or directly to the output of `(current-time)`.